# How to remove unused binding with self-reference using Babel

Tags: javascript, minify, babeljs

Given this input:

```js
const NOT_REFERENCED = 'abc';

class NotReferencedEither extends React.Component {
  static something() {
    // ...
  }
  someMethod() {
    NotReferencedEither.something();
  }
  render() {
    return <span>Foo</span>;
  }
}
```

And this Babel plugin:

```js
export default function ({types: t}) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Program(path, state) {
        Object.keys(path.scope.bindings).forEach(bindingName => {
          const binding = path.scope.bindings[bindingName];
          if (!binding.referenced) {
            binding.path.remove();
          }
        });
      },
    }
  };
}
```

I would expect to end up with an empty file. Unfortunately, since `NotReferencedEither` has references to itself, it doesn't pass the removal test.

How can I augment this plugin so that `NotReferencedEither`, having only references to itself, gets removed too?

Live example: http://astexplorer.net/#/SvYcw6Xggc/4

Comment: Worth noting: if you comment out the line `NotReferencedEither.something();` you end up with an empty file. It is, in fact, the self-reference that's the problem.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but dead code removal is a hard problem, especially in JS. What if `React.Component` were a getter that had side-effects? Then the real simplified version of this would be `React.Component;` on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure *why* this works since it is undocumented, but if you call `binding.path.scope.crawl()` before removing the path it works as expected as seen [here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0efe782aa661524c42ec4ed66c6cb23a/e09e57de998ccb10ea2a2c6dba556bee80b7faad).